# Distance on the sphere is convex

Tags: smooth-manifolds, spheres, spherical-geometry, geodesic, convex-geometry

Let $\mathbb{S}^n$ be the unit sphere and choose $p_0$ as the north pole. Consider the function $d:\mathbb{S}^n \to [0, \infty)$ defined by $d(p) = d(p,p_0) = \cos^{-1}( \langle p, p_0 \rangle)$. It is the intrinsec distance to $p_0$ in the sphere. Is this function convex?

In order to answer this question, we have to show that $d \circ \gamma$ is a convex function of a real variable, for any geodesic $\gamma$ of the sphere. I showed it for geodesics issuing from $p_0$. Is it enough?

Comment: Sorry. Geodesics through $p_0$ tell you only how the function behaves as you move away from $p_0$. They do not tell you how it behaves in other directions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you believe that $d$ is convex?

Comment: Look at $\Bbb S^2$ first. Consider a great circle slanted at 45 degrees. Calculate your function as a function of $\theta$ around the circle. Is that function convex everywhere?